# Double transformation of marker in Carto CSS

Tags: coordinate-system, tilemill, markers, cartocss

I need to show on the map the direction of the road traffic with arrows. For this purpose I use markers for Carto CSS in TileMill.

If the road has in OSM tag oneway="yes" or oneway="1", all is ok, but sometimes the tag is oneway="-1" that means my direction arrows should be rotated to 180 degrees. It would not be a big problem (marker-transform: "rotate(180,0,0)";) but at the same time I also need to scale my markers in different zooms (for ex., marker-transform: "scale(0.5)";).

I have no idea how to apply both transformations at the same time - I change their positions in the code but it shows me rather only first or second transformation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two separate `marker-transform` properties can't be applied for the same object, but if you can apply a single property with multiple functions in it:

```
marker-transform: 'scale(0.5) rotate(180)';
```

However this would likely require you rearrange your code to apply the correct rotations at the same time and make things more complicated.

A simpler approach would be to use the `marker-width` property to scale your arrows (specifying an explicit pixel value rather than a relative scaling value), and use `marker-transform` just for the rotation.

Comment: Thanx! It helped me a lot!